# Find the dimension of $\mathbb F[T]$ over $\mathbb F$

Tags: linear-algebra

The following question came in linear algebra exam:

> Let the degree of minimal polynomial $m(x)$ of $T$ be k. Find the dimension of $\mathbb F[T]$ over $\mathbb F$ .

Can anyone help out with how to proceed with the problem..

Comment: Show that $1,T,\ldots, T^{k-1}$ are linearly independent and generate $\mathbb F[T]$ (which I would prefer to be called $\mathbb F[X]/(m(X))$, by the way)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen  you prefer, say, $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{-5}]$ 'to be called'  $\mathbb{Q}[X]/ (X^2 +5)$? I don't.

Comment: @quid »$ℚ[\sqrt{-5}]$« is short for »$ℚ[X]/(X^2 + 5)$«. On the other hand, »$F[T]$ with $m(X)$ being the minimal polynomial of $T$« isn’t short for »$F[X]/(m)$«.

Comment: @k.stm perhaps I did chose a poor example to illustrate my points,  but my points are (too?) first that the two are in general not the same thing, and second even if they are/were it is not really desirable (IMO) to use the notation as a quotient ring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That the minimal polynomial has degree $k$ means that there is a polynomial $f(X)= a_0X^0 + a_1 X + \dots + a_{k-1}X^{k-1} + X^k$ such that $f(T)= 0$.

Thus $ T^k = -a_0T^0 - a_1 T - \dots - a_{k-1}T^{k-1} $.

So you see that $T^k$ can be expressed as a linear combination of $\{T^0, T^1, \dots, T^{k-1}\}$.

From this observation it is nor hard to show that $\{T^0, T^1, \dots, T^{k-1}\}$ spans the full space.

Then it remains to show that this set is in fact independent. If you assume it is not independent, then you get a non-trivial relation among these elements that would yield a non-zero polynomial of degree less than $k$ that annihilates $T$, contradicting the assumption that the *minimal* polynomial has degree $k$.